# Get kerberos ticket as file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kerberos

I am trying to get a kerberos ticket as a file.  The kerberos server is FreeIPA.

When I login using `kinit USERNAME` on the computer, It logs in just fine.  When I view the ticket using `klist`, it shows the information

```
Ticket cache: KEYRING:persistent:1000:1000
Default principal: cclloyd@EXAMPLE.com

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
08/15/2020 22:36:12  08/16/2020 22:36:08  krbtgt/EXAMPLE.COM@EXAMPLE.COM
```

It seems it's stored in a keyring.  How can I grab the file from that keyring?

Answer (score 1):

You can request the traditional, file-based ccache format through the `KRB5CCNAME` environment variable or the `-c` option:

```
$ export KRB5CCNAME="FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_$UID"
$ kinit
$ hexdump -C /tmp/krb5cc_$UID
```

Alternatively, if you're only interested in the individual tickets' contents, you can use `keyctl` to extract them (which are stored as separate keys):

```
$ pp=$(keyctl get_persistent @s)
$ keyctl show $pp
Keyring
 718513420 ---lswrv   2001 65534  keyring: _persistent.2001
 952719927 --alswrv   2001   100   \_ keyring: _krb
 986359066 --alswrv   2001   100       \_ user: krb_ccache:primary
1022423951 --alswrv   2001   100       \_ keyring: 2001
 741425749 --alswrv   2001   100           \_ user: __krb5_princ__
 350568129 --als-rv   2001   100           \_ big_key: krbtgt/EXAMPLE.ORG@EXAMPLE.ORG
```

Note down the key ID from the leftmost column, then use:

```
$ keyctl pipe 350568129 | dumpasn1
```

Finally you can use the libkrb5 API to iterate through credentials and dump `cred->ticket`; [example](https://github.com/grawity/code/blob/master/kerberos/pklist.c).